# "retrieving" a distribution from a scipy array of distributions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, statistics

I'm working in python using scipy and numpy. Let's say I want to do some stuff with a couple of Beta distributions. In particular I want to study Beta(1,4), Beta(2,5) and Beta(3,6). I can define `priorArray` which is a scipy distribution object, out of which I can draw arrays of values.

```
from scipy.stats import beta
import numpy as np

priorArray = beta((1,2,3),(4,5,6))

z = priorArray.pdf(0.3)
print type(z)
```

This seems to work as expected. But, if I want to extract one of the component distributions from this array of distributions (eg. Beta(2,4)):

```
priorArray[1]
```

this causes an error:

```
TypeError: 'rv_frozen' object does not support indexing
```

So `priorArray` is not the type of object I can index, even though a lot of the methods for the object return arrays of values as expected.

So my question is: is there a way extract a distribution from an array of distributions?

Comment: I assume you meant *"(eg. Beta(2,5)):"*.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser yup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recover the values that you passed to `beta` with the `args` attribute:

```
In [10]: priorArray = beta((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6))                                

In [11]: priorArray.args                                                        
Out[11]: ((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6))

In [12]: [p[1] for p in priorArray.args]                                        
Out[12]: [2, 5]
```

To iterate over the pairs of parameters, you could do:

```
In [14]: for a, b in zip(*priorArray.args): 
    ...:     print(a, b) 
    ...:                                                                        
1 4
2 5
3 6
```

Comment: I see, so to recover a frozen distribution I 'd do `beta(priorArray.args[1,:])` to extract beta(2,4)? Thanks

Comment: `args` is a tuple, not a numpy array, so that won't work.  When you say "recover a frozen distribution", do you mean you want to create a new frozen distribution with just the pair (2, 5)?  (Your `priorArray` is a frozen distribution that has, in effect, three sets of parameters: (1, 4), (2, 5) and (3, 6).)

Comment: Yes. Basically, I want to iterate over the sets of parameters, so yes I want to create a "new" frozen distribution. I need to turn the output of `args` into an array, which is fine. Thanks.

Comment: Can you also recover the type of distribution (i.e. beta) from a distribution object?